# WebTorrent-CLI (hybrid) don't seed torrents already downloaded

Tags: cmd, console, peer, torrent, webtorrent

I'm trying to seed a torrent (already downloaded) with webtorrent-cli (the hybrid version), but shows this message "torrent downloaded successfully from 3/55 peers in 13s!

webtorrent is exiting... "
I want that webtorrent keep seeding the torrent even though is already downloaded.
I'm using Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 1):

The docs on https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent-cli have this option:

```
--keep-seeding          don't quit when done downloading
```